# How can I limit the number of results of a specific part of an SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you see a way in the following SQL call to limit the number of results of just this specific part:

```
OR (u1 != '2' AND u2 != '2' AND u3 != '2' AND m.membership_id = 1 AND m.aff IN (SELECT id FROM members WHERE id != 2 AND membership_id = 1 OR jv > 0)))
```

I like to limit that number of matches to a exact number, e.g. 150

The full SQL is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mid, did FROM product_access, members AS m 
WHERE mid = m.id AND m.active = 1 
      AND m.suspended = 0 
      AND (u1 = '2' OR u2 = '2' OR u3 = '2' OR (u1 != '2' AND u2 != '2' AND u3 != '2' AND m.membership_id = 1 AND m.aff IN (SELECT id FROM members WHERE id != 2 AND membership_id = 1 OR jv > 0))) GROUP BY mid
```

So, the result should include all where `u1 = '2'`, all where `u2 = '2'`, all where `u3 = '2'`, but just 150 where:

```
(u1 != '2' AND u2 != '2' AND u3 != '2' AND m.membership_id = 1 AND m.aff IN (SELECT id FROM members WHERE id != 2 AND membership_id = 1 OR jv > 0))
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Could you please use still more and even shorter obfuscated short-code variables?

Comment: Try `SELECT TOP 150 ....`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Your question really doesn't make sense.  What about the other conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always make a subquery from every single part of your query and have it LIMITed to the n TOPmost entries.

From what I understand, something like this should suffice:

```
SELECT mid, did FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT mid, did FROM product_access, members AS m 
WHERE mid = m.id AND m.active = 1 
      AND m.suspended = 0 
      AND (u1 = '2' OR u2 = '2' OR u3 = '2')

UNION SELECT TOP 150 DISTINCT mid, did FROM product_access, members AS m 
WHERE mid = m.id AND m.active = 1 
     AND m.suspended = 0 
     AND (u1 != '2' AND u2 != '2' AND u3 != '2' AND m.membership_id = 1 AND m.aff IN (SELECT id FROM members WHERE id != 2 AND membership_id = 1 OR jv > 0))

) GROUP BY mid
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped...

SELECT mid, did FROM ( (
    SELECT DISTINCT mid, did FROM product_access, members AS m WHERE mid = m.id AND m.active = 1 AND m.suspended = 0 AND (u1 = '2' OR u2 = '2' OR u3 = '2') GROUP BY mid
    ) UNION (
    SELECT DISTINCT mid, did FROM product_access, members AS m WHERE mid = m.id AND m.active = 1 AND m.suspended = 0 AND (u1 != '2' AND u2 != '2' AND u3 != '2' AND m.membership_id = 1 AND m.aff IN (SELECT id FROM members WHERE id != 2 AND membership_id = 1 OR jv > 0)) GROUP BY mid LIMIT 150
    )) AS t

Answer (score 1):

If `SQL SERVER` Then use `TOP` , If `MY SQL` Then use `LIMIT`.

SQL-Server

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MyTable;
```

My SQL

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: It's MySQL... but isn't LIMIT limited to the complete query?  Or is it possible to apply that just to the part that is mentioned above?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the upvote ? This answer doesn't really fill OP requirements, which are to limit the number of results matching a part of the conditions, not all of them

Comment: I agree with @Logar.  Frank, please share you table schema, sample data & desired output.